# Elegant naming convention for pins with (many) multiple functions in gEDA

Tags: symbol, geda

I use gEDA suite for schematics and PCB layout and I sometimes need to create new components (i.e. `symbols`) for gEDA library is rather generic. Not a problem to me. But with the advent of micro-controllers it's not uncommon to have pins with many alternate functions.

In general pins are named against their functions, for instance `SDA` or `SCL`, `RESET`, `Vcc`, `Vdd`, you name it. But what do you do with pin names such as `PC1 (PCINT13/ADC10/ICP1/SCLUSCK/XCK1)` on the ATtiny1634?

[image]

Not only do I find such names ugly and impractical but they also tend to inflate the symbol, turning it into a fat block instead of an elegant rectangle... (Golden Ratio anyone?) Moreover extremely long pin names also clutter the PCB layout:

[image: Long pin names that spread]

Now I want the symbol to carry all the alternate functions but hidden, preferably. Ideally in gEDA the pin name would look like `pinlabel=PC1`. But how do you add the rest? I could only think of adding [hidden or not] `pinlabel` attributes.

> **pinlabel**
>
> This attribute labels a pin object. This attribute is primarily used by gnetlist to support hierarchical designs.
>   This attribute must be attached to the pin and be left visible. Please make this attribute green (instead of the default attribute yellow).

But gEDA documentation isn't clear; my question is: *does it allow for multiple `pinlabel` occurrences*?

Comment: I'll strike out with an opinion here rather than an answer, as I've struggled with this -- IMO, the schematic symbol in your library should reflect 100% what the datasheet of the part uses for labeling each pin. For MCUs, this means unfortunately a very long string due to many, many functions. Any NC pins, unused pins and exposed pads should also appear on the symbol IMO. It's 2016 -- schematic capture symbols do not need to reflect the physical layout of the chip anymore if you don't need it. You can even break a part into sub-symbols (factor out power for example) to improve readability.

Comment: @KrunalDesai Yes, I understand. I'm not trying to *hide* anything; I inappropriately used the term "hidden attributes" and I surprisingly enough got comments focused about hiding info being a bad thing, which I totally understand and agree upon but this is not my point. My point is, trying to keep all information at hand for documentation's sake, *does gEDA support multiple `pinlabel`*? as I pointed elsewhere. But I finally found something that suits me. I'll post the answer soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As many stressed on that, hiding information (i.e. pin functions) is not advisable. So far, so good, that was not the intent. The goal is twofold:

- make pin names somewhat "shorter" while keeping the necessary datasheet information about pin features
- prevent pin names from cluttering the PCB layout... whenever one needs to check the correct wiring of a newly created symbol/footprint.

The idea I had in mind was to split pin names into separate pin attributes, of which I'd use `pinlabel` multiple times. I still don't know if gEDA supports multiple pin labels but I found out using comments would just fit my requirements:

1. set `pinlabel` to the port name only
2. add a `comment` attribute to the pin with all the alternate functions of the pin.

**Split port name and alternate features in pin label and comment:**
[image: Pin label and comment]

**Align pin label and comment vertically:**
[image: Pin label and comment vertically aligned]

The space gain is not huge (though at least 6 characters across) but the following does the trick:

1. all pin information is kept visible
2. pin label is kept short for less PCB clutter
3. with smart pin placement, the symbol can be shrunk.

PCB layout shows pin labels with port names only for less clutter, more clarity:
[image: PCB shows pin labels only]

Symbol went physical, lost weight:
[image: Symbol shrunk]

Here's how the comment appears in the symbol definition file:

```
P 100 1900 400 1900 1 0 0
{
    T 450 1800 5 8 0 1 0 0 1
    pintype=io
    T 455 1895 9 8 1 1 0 0 1
    pinlabel=PC1
    T 305 1945 5 8 1 1 0 6 1
    pinnumber=16
    T 150 1750 5 8 0 1 0 0 1
    pinseq=14
    T 450 1775 9 8 1 1 0 0 1
    comment=PCINT13/ADC10/ICP1/SCL/USCK/XCK1
}
```

You can later toggle between showing pin names or numbers in PCB for further checking the pin label/number assignment with <kbd>D</kbd> and/or <kbd>N</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

While I am not aware of any real and direct rules about this I tend to use the scheme of Naming the Port and Pin, such as you do.

Then, if they have alternate functionality that is interesting, such as SPI, ICSP, DA, AD, UART, etc I usually add a note that is as short as possible, but still gives enough detail to quickly find the configurations needed in the datasheet of the two most likely or prevalent ones.

For example, the PCINT functionality in an Atmel controller is utterly uninteresting when routing or hooking up in 9 out of 10 models, as all pins have that, and as such it makes no distinction to the design of the schematic. Then if I have one of the very few Atmels with 2 or 3 pins without PCINT, I add that as a label to those pins "NO-PCI" for example, or if the block is large enough just "NO-PCINT".

Now, here comes in the fact that I can, in the design programs that I use for myself and customers, attach several properties to pins that need not be visible, but can be used for rule-checking. So I prefer in those packages to add "NO-PCINT" or "PCINT" to a general property and set up a design rule for "Not Allowed: Signal('REAL-TIME-IMPORTANT') WITH (PinType('NO-PCINT') AND PinType('NO-INT')" or some such.

#### //EDIT:Addition:

To add, this rule does make it so that one part with one package gets a set of 1 footprint and several symbols. All of "*my* software solutions" (costing Many-Cash(c) ) allow this to be done elegantly and without overhead. But it does add clarity to the schematics over having to read off a list of a bazillion options.

One thing I vigorously hate when developing FW for someone else is having to read through a whole bunch of words to find the intention of a pin, whereas I will need the Datasheet and Port&Pin number anyway to figure out what to configure and how.

i.e. The system using a Tiny841 for analogue monitoring would have the ADC labels and most likely PWM labels on the symbol, whereas one controlling all kinds of digital functions would have all SPI and I2C options labelled. There will of course always be exceptions, and probably all of them would show the program pins and the most likely UART pins.

Comment: Interesting. While I agree with you about `PCINT` the ID however is important to know... I guess. As for gEDA you need to edit the symbol to change pin names, attributes, aso. So that's a fairly good reason to me to do it once and for all.

Comment: @Nasha I am not saying it's stupid to fully name them in some packages that I have no recent experience with. In most Atmels, while not all, you will find PCINT just counts up from the first available pin alphabetically. So I found that one exceptionally boring in nearly all my designs to have visually available to me.

Comment: I may have worded my comment inappropriately. I meant I agree with you about PCINT being uselessly boring. By the way the same goes with `ADCn`, sort of. The useful thing is the «*n*» part in `PCINTn` or `ADCn`, which implies keeping that information in my case, be it to know, for instance, what register and bit goes with what `PCINT` pin.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of a schematic is to convey a circuit to the reader, with as much information as possible. Your AtTiny example does that perfectly fine. In fact, the firmware guys will thank you because now they don't have to go to the datasheet to know a pins alternate functions. No one cares if you schematic symbols are "elegant rectangles." That's not the point of a schematic.

You should really hide pin names on PCB layouts. All they do is clutter things up. As a PCB designer, all you really care about at that point are nets. Good EDA tools will have net names shown on traces and pins, scaled appropriately.

Comment: Hiding pin names on the PCB is not the point. Of course I do. But cluttered is cluttered anyway and it can become hard to *identify* pin names when you temporarily show pin labels on the PCB – which is especially important when *checking* a component you created.

Comment: @Nasha So basically what you're saying is it's not an issue anyway? Then what's the problem?

Comment: Uh? What is an issue is pin identification. To solve that issue, I need to make pin names shorter in space while keeping [alternate functions] on the symbol itself. Optionally, if shorter pin names do happen to not clutter the PCB layout, it's a bonus. So my question remains: «*does gEDA support more than one `pinlabel` per pin?*»